# Problem with Exporting an AOP Proxy as a Web Service - start is very long time

Tags: .net, asp.net-2.0, spring.net

I have an assembly named BusinessLayer. I would like to use its classes as web services. So i have done the following. I created new project (CompanyServices), referenced it to BusinessLayer and specified the following configuration params:

```
  <object id="SecureRepository" type="BaseSecureService.SecureRepository, BaseSecureService">
    </object>


    <object id="AuthenticationAdvice" type="BaseSecureService.AuthenticationAdvice, BaseSecureService">
        <property name="SecureRepository" ref="SecureRepository"/>
        <property name="SecureTriggersController" ref="SecureTriggersController"/>
    </object>


    <object id="baseServiceProxyFactoryObject" abstract="true">
        <property name="InterceptorNames">
            <list>
                <value>AuthenticationAdvice</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </object>
    <object id="baseSecureServiceExporter" abstract="true">
        <property name="WebServiceBaseType" value="BaseSecureService.SecureWebService, BaseSecureService" />
        <property name="MemberAttributes">
            <dictionary>
                <entry key="*">
                    <object type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute, System.Web.Services">
                        <constructor-arg value="AuthenticationHeader" />
                    </object>
                </entry>
            </dictionary>
        </property>
    </object>
```

(This is to control security params automatically)

A service example:

```
<object id="ReportProxy" type="Spring.Aop.Framework.ProxyFactoryObject, Spring.Aop" parent="baseServiceProxyFactoryObject">
        <property name="Target" ref="ReportController"/>
    </object>

    <object id="ReportService" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter, Spring.Web" parent="baseSecureServiceExporter">
        <property name="TargetName" value="ReportProxy" />
    </object>
```

It works, but the problem is that first call to a web service is too slow.ASP.NET application using BusinessLayer starts significantly faster.
Is there a way to make CompanyServices start faster?
Or maybe another way to implement this (using BusinessLayer classes as web services)?

So, in finaly i have so spring logs

```
2011-08-12 16:13:55,414 [INFO ] Spring.Aop.Framework.ProxyFactoryObject - Implemented interfaces have changed; reseting singleton instance
2011-08-12 16:14:16,158 [DEBUG] Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory - Invoking IObjectPostProcessors after initialization of object 'ReportProxy'


2011-08-12 16:14:16,159 [DEBUG] Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory - Calling AfterPropertiesSet() on object with name 'ReportService'.
2011-08-12 16:14:36,395 [DEBUG] Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory - Invoking IObjectPostProcessors after initialization of object 'ReportService'
```

What do I do not truly?